# Make the image background in whole background

Tags: java, android

I want to make my login activity with background off whole activity including clock of the phone itself Like this

[image]

This is my code

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bgd2"
    tools:context=".Signin">
```

But my output is this

[image]

I need to remove the orange bar and make it the same image like the first image.

How can I make it according to this style:

```
  <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">#FFF</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">#FFF</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove the ActionBar color using NoActionBar style.

there are two options.

1. put the windowNoTitle style in style.xml
   example :

   `<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
       <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
       <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
   </style>`
2. Put this code on the Activity.

   `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

   getSupportActionBar().hide();`

addition :
 if you also hide the navigation buttons then use FullScreen option in the style XML.

```
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```